# Странное поведение препроцессора

Tags: c++, препроцессор

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
class Type
{
  public:
    void Method(){};
};

#define Method ...

int main()
{
    Type type;
    type.Method();
    return 0;
}
```

Является ли нормальной ситуация, при которой препроцессор заменяет `Method` в `type.Method()` содержимым макроопределения `Method`?

Comment: Да. Препроцессор просто заменяет один кусок текста на другой. В чем, по-вашему, такого особенно в конструкции `type.Method()`? В том, что это вызов метода, верно? Но препроцессор ничего об этом не знает и просто заменяет одно на другое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае `Method` - отдельное слово, так что все нормально.

Вот если бы он заменял часть из `MyMethod` - тогда да, это было бы неверно.

Препроцессор ничего не знает о синтаксисе языка.

Comment: Как раз о **синтаксисе языка** препроцессор знает достаточно, чтобы разбить текст на лексемы и делать макроподстановки только подходящих

Comment: @avp Ну, тогда не знаю, как верно ответить.

Comment: Ну, суть-то ответа (что Method это отдельное слово) от замечания о знаниях препроцессора не меняется, он меняет те синтаксические единицы, которые являются идентификаторами  (т.е. отдельными словами). Поэтому он правильно заплюсован и принят

Comment: @avp, я бы не сказал, что препроцессор знает что-то об «идентификаторах»: например, `return` идентификатором не является, но препроцессор с радостью его заменит...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, да, с терминологией дело темное, но наверное, все же знает. Пишут, что "[You may define any valid **identifier** as a macro, even if it is a C keyword](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html#Macros)".

Comment: @avp, мда... соглашусь, что не так всё однозначно с терминологией...